# Meta tables for H2 db in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch, h2

I am facing some trouble in order to configuring spring batch with h2 db 
My configuration looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration implements BatchConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Driver.class.getName());
        String h2Url = MessageFormat.format("jdbc:h2:file:{0}note;MODE=Oracle", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));           
        LOGGER.info("Using H2 with URL : {}", h2Url);
        dataSource.setUrl(h2Url);
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultPersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager() {
        DefaultPersistenceUnitManager defaultPersistenceUnitManager = new DefaultPersistenceUnitManager();
        defaultPersistenceUnitManager.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath*:/META-INF/persistence.xml");
        defaultPersistenceUnitManager.setDefaultDataSource(dataSource());
        return defaultPersistenceUnitManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(H2Dialect.class.getName());
        jpaAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        jpaAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return jpaAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myEmf() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceUnitManager());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaAdapter());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
    }

    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean factory = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setTablePrefix("BATCH_");
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(myEmf().getObject());
    }

}
```

When i start my job , it cannot connect to the db because the configuration is unable to retrieve the metadata ( while checking into the spring batch core. jar, i can find the h2 db schemas ) so i get the exception :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found;
```

Any help would be appreciated 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1. That Exception isn't from not being able to connect to the database, but because the tables haven't been created (that Exception indicates that you can connect to the database).  I don't see you running the initialization scripts.
2. You're overdoing all the wiring.  Based on what you're doing, you shouldn't need to implement `BatchConfigurer`.  All you need to provide is the `DataSource` bean.  The rest should be provided for you...

Comment: Thank you very much , i add like you suggested "'init=runscript from 'classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql'" in the h2 url and it works great now. But please , can you explain me what 's the use to implement BatchConfigurer or not ? Thanks

Comment: By default, we provide the configuration in the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` when you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`.   The only time you need to implement `BatchConfigurer` is when you wan to change that configuration.  In your case, since most of the configuration in your implementation is the same as ours, you can just extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and override what you need.